# How to get multiple checkbox value on button click from an Onsen Checkbox?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, onsen-ui

I am using ons-checkbox provided by Onsen-UI, I have multiple checbox

`<ons-checkbox input-id = "brand" value = "example" class = "checkbox"></ons-checkbox>`

on the button click I want to get the values of all the checked checkboxes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*checkbox.html*

```
<ons-page>
  <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 30px;">
    <p style="margin-top: 30px;">
      <ons-button onclick="checkedData()">Data</ons-button>
    </p>
    <ons-list>
    <ons-list-item tappable>
      <label class="left">
        <ons-checkbox input-id="check-1" value="Apple"></ons-checkbox>
      </label>
      <label for="check-1" class="center">
        Apple
      </label>
    </ons-list-item>
    <ons-list-item tappable>
      <label class="left">
        <ons-checkbox input-id="check-2" value="Banana"></ons-checkbox>
      </label>
      <label for="check-2" class="center">
        Banana
      </label>
    </ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>

  </div>
</ons-page>
```

*checkbox.js*

```
var checkedData = function() {
  var ons = document.getElementsByTagName('ons-checkbox');
  for (var i=0; i<ons.length; i++) {
    if(ons[i].checked) {
      // Below will give all checked values
      console.log('Checked Values : , ons[i].value);
    } else {
      // Below will give all un-checked values
      console.log('Un-Checked Values : , ons[i].value);
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks @solanki... it worked but instead of getElementByTagName, I have used querySelectorAll to get all the checkboxes by classname

Comment: @KunalTyagi : Yes, go ahead, u can use.

Comment: Hi @solanki is there any way that we can get the value of all the unchecked checkboxes, if you could please help

Comment: OK. Let me check this.

Comment: @KunalTyagi : Now check my answer